# g++ opimization Archlinux

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora, archlinux

I have an interesting problem. I used to write my project under Fedora 23 and everything was just fine. 
I compiled my code like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Ofast linked_list.cpp -o link.out
```

But a couple days ago I switched to Arch linux and from now on, when I'm trying to compile project like this, I'm getting twise worst result then before. On Fedora it was around 6.2-5.8 sec. On Arch 16-15 sec.

Also I have tried the link.out that was compiled in Fedora and it gave me stable 5 sec. 
So do I miss any libs or something like that?

Comment: Fedora 23 has gcc version 5.1.1, which version are you using on Arch ? What else have changed besides the distro ?

Comment: On Arch it's 5.2.0.
That's the problem. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Maybe you could try to compile with version 5.2.0 on Fedora too. So you can see if the issue comes from gcc or Archlinux.

Comment: Can you maybe also show the interesting part of the code?